# How to make the layout scrollable when the keyboard is active?

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, keyboard

I have a register layout. In this if I click on first edit text the keyboard appears and other views gets hidden under the keyboard. So I want to make the layout scrollable so we can scroll up and use the next edit text while the keyboard is popped up.

I tried to add the scroll view for this in layout. Also set this   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest for the activity. But it makes all the views shift up , so all the layouts got merged with each other.

Following is the image what I got.

[image]

EDIT: Edited layout : Edited again.Still it works same.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/login" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
                android:background="@drawable/field_1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/user" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" android:hint="@string/user_id"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/field_1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/email"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" android:hint="EMAIL "
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:background="@drawable/field_1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/pass" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textPassword|text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:background="@drawable/field_1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/phone" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="+91"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background = "@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="05dp">
                </View>
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:hint="MOBILE NO"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="SIGN UP"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:id="@+id/alreadyRegistered"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How to do this?

Doing same with another layout, but in this when I click on first edit text , the first edit text also scrolls up while the keyboard is popped up. What's wrong here? Used this too.

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
        android:background="@drawable/field_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:hint="First Name"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
        android:background="@drawable/field_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDOB"
        android:background="@drawable/field_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Date Of Birth"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:inputType="date" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLocation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
        android:background="@drawable/field_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Location"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAnniversary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
        android:background="@drawable/field_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Anniversary"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:inputType="date" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
        android:background="@drawable/field_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Identify Family Members In Contacts"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSecondName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make scrollview root of the layout

Comment: I tried this, please check the edited question . @MarkoNiciforovic

Comment: it is not root, root = 1st view of your layout.. as I can see  your root is relative layout

Comment: please check edited again still works same. @MarkoNiciforovic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use`Scroll View` as Your `Root Layout`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

> Also add this to your `Manifest`.

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Comment: tried this please check the edited question. @jaydroider

Comment: could u please check with another login layout? please check the edited question. Thank you. @jaydroider

Comment: Try by adding this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` in your `Manifest`  **OR** `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`.

Comment: yes I tried this with those layout by adjusting layouts i got the result well., now for the another fragment layout when i tried to add the scroll view it scrolls the first text view also and it goes below the toolbar layout ,when i clicked on first edit text.@jaydroider

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your layout root to ScrollView Instead of RelativeLayout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<!--Your layout components-->


<!--Your layout components-->

</ScrollView
```

In your manifest.xml add this to your activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: I have tried this please check the edited question. @BOUTERBIAT Oualid

Comment: make first root as ScrollView instead of RelativeLyout wich you'll make it under ScrollView

Comment: please check edited again still works same. @BOUTERBIAT Oualid

Comment: It's not scrolling with this. @BOUTERBIAT Oualid

Comment: could u please check with another login layout? please check the edited question. Thank you.@BOUTERBIAT Oualid